# How to show that $\sqrt{2+ \sqrt{s_n}}$ is increasing

Tags: real-analysis

I'm working on a problem in Rudin concerning the convergence of the sequence $\{ s_n \}$ defined by

$$s_1 = \sqrt 2, \quad s_{n+1} = \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{s_n}}$$

I have established that the sequence is bounded above by $2$. I would like to invoke the monotone convergence theorem, but I am unsuccessful in showing that $s_{n+1} \ge s_n$. I was trying an induction proof but it did not work out. Is this the correct approach?

Comment: root $s_n$ is $\geq 0$

Comment: @Harish I'm not quite sure how that helps

Comment: $$s_{n+1}>s_n \iff \sqrt{2+\sqrt{s_n}}>s_n \iff s_n^2-\sqrt{s_n}-2>0$$which is true for $s_n>1.831$ (unfortunately I found that only graphically). Since $s_2 \approx 1.84$ you can show this for all $n$ but induction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try induction.

1. If $s_{k+1}>s_k>0$ then $\sqrt{s_{k+1}}>\sqrt{s_k}$.
2. So if $s_{k+1}>s_k>0$ then $\sqrt{2+\sqrt{s_{k+1}}}>\sqrt{2+\sqrt{s_{k}}}>0$.

   > 3. So if $s_{k+1}>s_k>0$ then $s_{k+2}>s_{k+1}>0$

And don't forget the base case.

Comment: I would be surprised if this is not an essential duplicate of an older answer :-(

Comment: This proof is so beautiful. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

- Let $x$ be the positive solution to $x=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{x}}$.
- Show that $s_n \leq x$.
- Show that $s_n \geq 1.5$ for all $n \geq 2$.
- Now prove that $s_{n+1} > s_n$ using the fact that $(y^2-2)^2-y$ is an increasing function on the interval $[1.5,x]$.

Comment: You need to prove that there is only one positive solution in your first point.