# Suppose that $s_1 = \sqrt{2}$ and $s_{n+1}=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{s_n}}$. Show that $s_n<2$ for all $n$ and that $s_n$ converges

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $s_1 = \sqrt{2}$ and $s_{n+1}=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{s_n}}$. Show that $s_n<2$ for all $n$ and that $s_n$ converges

(Chapter 3 exercise 3 of baby Rudin)

Showing that $s_n < 2$ for all $n$ is an easy induction. The base case is part of the hypothesis of the problem. Suppose this inequality holds for $n$.

Then:

$s_{n+1}=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{s_n}} < \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}} < \sqrt{2+2} = 2$

Thus $\sqrt{2} < s_n < 2$ for all $n$.

I'm trying to show that this sequence is increasing (which it clearly is!!!). Since every bounded monotonge sequence converges, the problem will be finished.

I need help with this part >.<

Notice that
$(s_n-\sqrt{2})(s_n-2)<0$ for all $n$. Maybe this will be uesful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Worth remarking that the associate fixed point is not apparent.  Easy to work it out, of course, but it's fairly random looking.

Comment: Feel free to expand on this :-P. What associated fixed point are you talking about? (be patient with me I'm sort of slow!!)

Comment: The limit.  Since your sequence is strictly increasing and bounded above by $2$, it approaches a limit $L$.  $L$ must have the property that $L=\sqrt {2+\sqrt {L}}$.  which you can solve, but it isn't pretty.  Easier to just run the sequence out a bit, it converges really fast to $1.8311772$.  Which, like I say, random looking.

Comment: Barring arithmetic error (always possible) I see the "closed form" as $L=\frac 13\times \left(-1+ 
\sqrt[3] {\frac {79-3\sqrt {249}}2}+\sqrt[3] {\frac {79+3\sqrt {249}}2}\right)$  which is awful,

Comment: Probable duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1575258/how-to-show-that-sqrt2-sqrts-n-is-increasing

Comment: >.< I figured this was somewhere already... I swear I looked and couldn't find it!! Ugh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Suppose that $s_1 = \sqrt{2}$ and $s_{n+1}=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{s_n}}$. Show that $s_n<2$ for all $n$ and that $s_n$ converges

You have shown that the sequence is bounded above by $2$.

Therefore, it is sufficient to show that the sequence is strictly increasing.

By inspection, $s_2 > s_1.$

Suppose that $s_n > s_{n-1}.$

Then $s_{n+1} = \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{s_n}} > \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{s_{n-1}}} = s_n.$

Comment: Or take $s_0=0$ which makes it trivial that $s_1 > s_0$.

Comment: @lhf +1 : elegant.  However, although a valid approach, I wouldn't use this approach with a new Math student, because they will not be sure that the approach is valid.  What might confuse them is that the value of $s_0 = 0$ is *inferred*, rather than explicit.